# i want to show onclick="toggle_visibility('form')" and onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')" in one click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use this two functions for one link.

`onclick="toggle_visibility('form')"` and 
`onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')"`

like

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')" onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')" style="text-decoration:none">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('form'); loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml');"
```

Should do the trick!